# How to check if a queryset inside a queryset is empty or not

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-testing

Im new in django and I made an **Idea** list with **options** just like **polls** but whenever I wanted to make sure that Ideas with no option is not displayed on index page I couldnt found any way to get the primary key of Ideas to check is there any option for it or not
I need all these to make a test for it
here is how I get option_set of an specific Idea:

```
idea = Idea.ojects.get(pk='primary key of idea')
idea.option_set.all()
```

moreover the Idea list has been filterd by their date and only with past date is displaying as below:

```
Idea.objects.filter(date__lte=timezone.now())
```

I tryed for loop as:

```
for obj in Idea.objects:
    if obj.option_set:
        ****
```

but the error was:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'Manager' object is not iterable
```

also I tryed nested loop but that wasnt the way

as I mentioned at first Im a bigenner so if there is any free tutorial better than django-docs *https://www.djangoproject.com/start/* I'll be verry happy to know about.